# SSIS job runing display in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a sharepoint 2010 site I would like to display a message in when the job that populates it with new data has started. On my old 2007 site we had a bit of javascript that read an system updated date in a file and displayed the date on site. We now want to display an interactive message also when it starts in SSIS.

I was thinking along the lines of writing something to a file from SSIS once the job starts like "Job has started" then using javascript code in webpart to read this file every 20 seconds or so and when it is not empty display the value in it; also when finished show "Job finished" for say 5 minutes then clear back to empty so it displays nothing.

Not entirely confident about the way forward to do this so some help or insight would be much appreciated. The bit getting me most is how to actually read the file from the javascript in the Webpart every 20 seconds or so and the timings for the other parts like showing job finished for 5 minutes etc; i've not used javascript much so hence the limited knowledge.

Thanks

A

Answer (score 0):

How is the SSIS job triggered? If it's SQL job, why not add steps to write a static peice of HTML to the web site that is incorportated into the sharepoint page as static text? The User can then refresh as needed.

Comment: SSIS job is triggered from a SQL task job, part of the issue is that the user gets notification of the start of the job by email but in some cases they may not see the email and instead if they are on the site they can then see a display saying the job has started. My feeling is that maybe this won't display until the page has refreshed so again it will be up to the user to remember to refresh the page every few minutes, which I do not want to rely on as you can understand.

Comment: So why not just put a javscript refresh (every x minutes) on the page and use the technique as suggested to put the data there?

Comment: There isn't a web site on the sharepoint page, not sure where that came from?